# Kafka producer time outs in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We are getting below exception with Kafka 2.11 and wso2 esb 6.2 with sasl enabled. SASL mechanism in wso2 esb and Kafka clsuter is PALIN but randmoly seeing Error 2 in logs.

Does anybody experienced this error and any help is appreciated.

Error 1:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for TESTTOPIC: 30051 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time

Error 2:
[2019-11-02 01:36:50,265] ERROR -  [Producer clientId=producer-4526] Connection to node -1 failed authentication due to: Unexpected handshake request with client mechanism PLAIN, enabled mechanisms are [GSSAPI] {org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient}

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Second Error Message `*Unexpected handshake request with client mechanism PLAIN, enabled mechanisms are [GSSAPI]*`, it would seem that the saslMechanism has not been configured properly on the ESB side. It is configured to GSSAPI Kerberos by default.

I would recommend getting the latest version of the Kafka Connector. You can find the documentation and the relevant links [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Kafka+Connector+and+Inbound)

One such example of a PLAIN configuration with the Kafka Connector would be :

```
<kafkaTransport.init>
        <bootstrapServers>localhost:9092</bootstrapServers>
        <keySerializerClass>org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer</keySerializerClass>
        <valueSerializerClass>org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer</valueSerializerClass>
        <securityProtocol> SASL_PLAINTEXT </securityProtocol>
        <saslMechanism> PLAIN </saslMechanism>
        <saslJaasConfig>org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="admin" password="12345"</saslJaasConfig>
        <maxPoolSize>100</maxPoolSize>
</kafkaTransport.init>
```

This is the relevant configuration required to make use of the Kafka Connector. The Security Protocol can be configured to SASL_SSL as well.

Here is one such proxy configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="KafkaTransport"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <kafkaTransport.init>
            <bootstrapServers>localhost:9092</bootstrapServers>
            <keySerializerClass>org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer</keySerializerClass>
            <valueSerializerClass>org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer</valueSerializerClass>
            <securityProtocol>SASL_SSL</securityProtocol>
            <saslMechanism>PLAIN</saslMechanism>

            <sslKeystoreLocation>/Users/Ibaqu/kafka.client.keystore.jks</sslKeystoreLocation>
            <sslKeystorePassword>admin123</sslKeystorePassword>

            <sslTruststoreLocation>/Users/Ibaqu/kafka.client.trustore.jks</sslTruststoreLocation>
            <sslTruststorePassword>admin123</sslTruststorePassword>
            <saslJaasConfig>org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="admin" password="12345";</saslJaasConfig>
            <maxPoolSize>100</maxPoolSize>
         </kafkaTransport.init>
         <kafkaTransport.publishMessages>
            <topic>test</topic>
         </kafkaTransport.publishMessages>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

You can give this particular proxy a try to test your connection.